# How can I snapshot `/usr/local` in OpenSUSE?

Tags: opensuse

[The OpenSuse Docs](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP5/html/SLES-all/cha-snapper.html#snapper-dir-excludes) say this about `/usr/local`:

"This directory is used when manually installing software. It is excluded to avoid uninstalling these installations on rollbacks."

However I want to snapshot it so I can easily roll it back when I rollback zypper installs (specifically cuda).

I tried adding a snapper config for `/usr/local` but got this error:

```
$ sudo snapper list-configs
Config | Subvolume
-------+----------
root   | /
$ sudo snapper create-config /usr/local
Creating config failed (config already exists).
```

Here's my current root config, which says nothing about `/usr/local`.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/snapper/configs/root

# subvolume to snapshot
SUBVOLUME="/"

# filesystem type
FSTYPE="btrfs"

# btrfs qgroup for space aware cleanup algorithms
QGROUP="1/0"

# fraction or absolute size of the filesystems space the snapshots may use
SPACE_LIMIT="0.5"

# fraction or absolute size of the filesystems space that should be free
FREE_LIMIT="0.2"

# users and groups allowed to work with config
ALLOW_USERS=""
ALLOW_GROUPS=""

# sync users and groups from ALLOW_USERS and ALLOW_GROUPS to .snapshots
# directory
SYNC_ACL="no"

# start comparing pre- and post-snapshot in background after creating
# post-snapshot
BACKGROUND_COMPARISON="yes"

# run daily number cleanup
NUMBER_CLEANUP="yes"

# limit for number cleanup
NUMBER_MIN_AGE="1800"
NUMBER_LIMIT="2-10"
NUMBER_LIMIT_IMPORTANT="4-10"

# create hourly snapshots
TIMELINE_CREATE="no"

# cleanup hourly snapshots after some time
TIMELINE_CLEANUP="yes"

# limits for timeline cleanup
TIMELINE_MIN_AGE="1800"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_HOURLY="10"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_DAILY="10"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_WEEKLY="0"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_MONTHLY="10"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_YEARLY="10"

# cleanup empty pre-post-pairs
EMPTY_PRE_POST_CLEANUP="yes"

# limits for empty pre-post-pair cleanup
EMPTY_PRE_POST_MIN_AGE="1800"
```

Comment: PS this root config is just for the root subvolume (`/@/` which is mounted to `/` by using the BTRFS default mount ID), not to be confused with the BTRFS-ROOT subvolume (subvolid=5, `/`)

Answer (score 0):

In default `/usr/local` is not being added to snapper (auto snapshot mechanic).

I suggest to manually create snapshots, it's really not that hard.

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /usr/local /usr/local.read-only-snapshot-01
```

...creates a read-only snapshot from `local` and names it `local.read-only-snapshot-01`.

Important, BTRFS subvolumes can be created/mounted in different ways, usually opensuse creates all subvolumes in a super subvolume just called `@` and uses the `/etc/fstab` to mount the different subvolumes. Another aproach would be to just create the subvolumes right at their place where they shall belong, using the `btrfs subvolume create` command.

To be able to directly access the super subvolume you need to mount the BTRFS-ROOT subvolume using its subvolid, which is always `5`.

```
mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=5 /dev/BTRFS_DEVICE /mnt/
```

When you want to revert to a previous snapshot, you can achive this by:

```
btrfs subvolume delete /usr/local
btrfs property set -ts /usr/local.read-only-snapshot-01 ro false
mv /usr/local.read-only-snapshot-01 /usr/local
```

Please take note that this approach might collide with your settings in your `/etc/fstab` (this depends how your BTRFS was setup), an easy workaround would be to just delete the entry belonging to `/usr/local/` in your `fstab`.